# What does it mean bundler (default: 1.16.2) when I run "gem list"? What's the (defailt) part?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I got this error message:

> .rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

I reinstalled Ruby

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.5.1
```

it gives an error message:

```
Error running '__rvm_with ruby-2.5.1 gemset_pristine', please read
/home/zoli/.rvm/log/1533209563_ruby-2.5.1/gemset.pristine-ruby-2.5.1.log
```

This is how I first run into this error:

```
$ gem list bun
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (default: 1.16.2)
```

Gem list gives a list of gems - some includes (default: ...) part. What does it mean?
I ran into this Github thread: bundler https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6290
which has the same issue:

```
(default: 1.16.1, default: 1.16.0)
```

It gives an error when I try to run commands with Ruby gems.

How to install Rubies with RVM without using any binary? What does this (default) part mean?

Answer (score 2):

The `default` part lists the default gem versions, the ones that are part of a specific Ruby.

You can find a list of default gems per Ruby version at https://stdgems.org/. Quote from that same site:

> There are two different kinds of standard gems:
>
> - Default gems: These gems are part of Ruby and you can always require them directly. You cannot remove them. They are maintained by Ruby
>     core.
> - Bundled gems: The behavior of bundled gems is similar to normal gems, but they get automatically installed when you install Ruby. They
>     can be uninstalled and they are maintained outside of Ruby core.